# $V=V^*$? the dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$. Let $U,W$ be the subspaces, and assume that $V$ is the direct sum $U\oplus W$. Show that $V^*$ is equal to the direct sum  $U^{\perp}\oplus W^{\perp}$.

I am aware the dual space has the same dimension. "***Theorem***:The map of $v\to L_v$ of $V$ into $V^*$ is an isomorphism."

I guess $U^{\perp}=W$ and $W^{\perp}=U$, so $U^{\perp}\oplus W^{\perp}=U^{\perp}+W^{\perp}$.

But unless $K=1$

I am not seeing how $U^{\perp}\oplus W^{\perp}\in V^{*}$ because that would imply V*=V, right?

**Questions**:

**1)** Is $V=V^{*}$?

**2)** How can I complete the proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Referencing the orthogonal complement $U^{\perp}$ does not make sense unless $V$ is an inner product space. Is this meant to be the case?

Comment: If you look at the definition of $U^{\perp}$, it is almost certainly defined to be 

$$U^{\perp} = \{ f \in V^{\ast} : f(u) = 0 \textrm{ for all } u \in U \}$$

Comment: @D_S ah, that makes much more sense.

Comment: In this sense, the notation $U^0$ is to be preferred.

Comment: @D_S  Are you saying that V must be zero, I mean all its elements zero?

Comment: @Bernard Could you further explain $U^0$ notation? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @PedroGomes no.  But $V^{\perp}$ will be zero.  More generally, $\textrm{dim}(W) = \textrm{dim}(V) - \textrm{dim}(W^{\perp})$ for any subspace $W$ of $V$.

Comment: @PedroGomes: By definition, $$U^0=\{\varphi\in V^*\mid \varphi\rvert_U=0\}.$$  This notation is often used because the *pairing* $\begin{aligned}[t] V\times V^*&\to\mathbf R\\(v,\varphi)&\mapsto \varphi(v\end{aligned}$ is not an *inner* product.

Comment: @Bernard             But I still can choose one element of $V^{*}$ like $\langle v_1,v\rangle$ in which v stands for all $v\in V$, so I do not need to do the pairing, right?

Comment: @Bernard I have never seen this before$\begin{aligned}[t] V\times V^*&\to\mathbb{R}$, the closest thing to this expression I saw was the theorem to prove $dim V=dimV^{*}$.

Comment: It's called a *bilinear pairing*. It looks very much like an inner product, except $v$ and $\varphi$ do not lie in the same space. In the proof that $\dim V=\dim V^*$, I suppose it was used without giving it a name, at it's not very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**: You are not wrong with the statement $V=V^*$, but they are only congorphic, so i think it would be better to write as $V \cong V^*$. For the purpose of the second question, this statement is not useful and i suggest you ignore it.

**2**:
Here i will use the definition
$$
 U^\perp = \{f\in V^*: f(u)=0 \forall u\in U\}.
$$
Using this definition (which is very common!) we can see that $U^\perp\subset V^*$.

For the direct sum you have to show two things: First, that $U^\perp \cap W^\perp=\{0\}$.
Second, that $V^*=U^\perp+W^\perp$.

The first property is easier to show (try it).
For the second property, let $f\in V^*$ be given.
Note that $f$ is uniquely defined by its values on $U$ and $W$.

So we can define $f_U,f_W \in V^*$ as
$$
 f_U(u+w) = f(u) \quad,\quad f_W(u+w) = f(w).
$$
where $u \in U$ and $w\in W$.
(it might be necessary to show that these are well-defined).

Then $f_U \in W^\perp$ and $f_W\in U^\perp$ (why?).
Finally $f = f_U+f_W \in W^\perp +U^\perp$, thus completing the proof of question 2.

There might be easier proofs, depending on what tools you have available, but the above is rather elemtary and you can get maybe a better feeling for dual spaces and $U^\perp$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean by $f = f_U+f_W \in W^perp +U^\perp$?

Comment: that was a typo. I mean that $f=f_U + f_W$ and $f_U+f_W \in W^\perp + U^\perp$.

Comment: Should $f_U(u+w) = f(u) \quad,\quad f_W(u+w) = f(w)$ be instead f_U(u+w) = f(w) \quad,\quad f_W(u+w) = f(u) once $f_U(u)=0\:\:\text{and}\:\:f_W(w)=0$. I am asking this because if f_U is a functional that acts only upon the subspace U and f_W upon the subspace W, then $V^{*}$ would be zero and $f = f_U+f_W \notin W^\perp +U^\perp$? right?

Comment: $f_U$ as defined in my answer acts on $V$, not just $U$. But $f_U$ is zero on $W$.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. I appreciate your answers but I still cannot understand why $f_U(w)=0$ if $w\notin U$.

Comment: that is not what i said. it is only $f_U(w)$ if $w \in W$.

Comment: But if $f_U$ acts upon the whole of V and $w\not in U$ then $f = f_U+f_W \in W^\perp +U^\perp$. If $f_U(w)=0$ and$ f_W(u)=0$ then $V^{*}$ would be zero. Thanks for your replies!